# Using PIL to produce combined image with 6 bands

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, cmyk, color-management

I am aware we can merge 4 monochromatic tifs in to one colored tiff using the merge function in PIL.

```
mergedRaster = Image.merge('CMYK', (c_img, m_img, y_img, k_img))
mergedRaster = mergedRaster.convert("CMYK")
```

But I need to merge 6 bands CMYK + 2 special color bands. How would I got about doing it ?

I have made the necessary changes in IMage module py files(Image.py, ImageMode.py) to include CMYKOG(Cyan Magenta Yellow Black Orange Green) as a color model, but I am getting an error raised from the _imaging.so file saying invalid color mode. How can I edit the .so file to incorporate the 6 band color mode ?

Or alternatively is there an easier way to combine 6 bands in to one tiff ?

Comment: Could you explain why you need a new color model? What is returned when you call `im.mode` on each of the monochrome images?

Comment: I am using a CMYK color model+spot colors(any special color which you may not want to map the cmyk, in my case green and orange)